# h:commandbutton not working in <o:form>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

```
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

<o:form includeViewParams="true">
  <h:commandButton value="Home" action="/index?faces-redirect=true"/>
  <p:dataTable> 

  </p:dataTable>
</o:form>
```

The h:commandButton is not working under the o:form. When I click on it, it remains on the same page. But when I change to h:form, it works. Nevertheless I need to use o:form for the includeViewParams. Is there any way I could resolve this?

Comment: can you post you whole code ?

Comment: i'm doing on another computer without internet access. It would be difficult to post everything. But mainly it is just a simple dataTable with lazy loading and a Home button.

Comment: what is `o` there ? like `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` `h` for jsf html tags

Comment: oh. Sorry for missing that out. I'm using omni faces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This construct works for me, as in, it actually navigates to `/index`. Only the view params disappear from the URL because you're forcing a redirect. But there is more, the `<h:commandButton>` is here essentially the wrong tool for the purpose. You want pure page-to-page navigation. You should then not be using a command link/button at all, but a plain link/button. You need `<h:button>`.

```
<h:button value="Home" outcome="/index" includeViewParams="true" />
```

Note: this doesn't require any form.

#### See also:

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one)